# Is there another, more efficient way to nest prefix and name prefix in laravel 8 that doesn't need to use so many groups?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I saw a good way to nest prefix and name prefix, but this is so verbose. In addition, for few requests, it's acceptable, but when there is a lot of requests, creating groups can be problematic. This is a toy example.

```
Route::prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::name('auth.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('login', [MainController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
        Route::get('register', [MainController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
    });
});
```

I try this, but it failed.

```
Route::name('auth.')->group(['prefix'=>'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('login', [MainController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::get('register', [MainController::class, 'register'])->name('register');
});
```

Is there another, more efficient way to nest prefix and name prefix in laravel 8 that doesn't need to use so many groups?

I'm using the [Laravel 8 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups)'s route group section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your `prefix`es, `name`s and `middleware`s in the `group` function which will tidy things up somewhat:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'as' => 'auth.'], function () {
    Route::get('login', [MainController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::get('register', [MainController::class, 'register'])->name('register')
});
```

If you want to specify `middleware` on the group, just add it to the array in the first argument for the `group` function.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'as' => 'auth.', 'middleware' => [...]], function () {
    ...
});
```